Hibernate Spatial not recognizing my @query st_dwithin method
hey i would like to get some help, i use hibernate 6.5, i followed the documentions and everything, and use jts to add geometeric point to my entity in my project :
@Entity
@Table(name = "OBJECTS_TBL")
public class ObjectEntity {
    @Id
    private String objectId;
    
    private String type;

    private String alias;

    private Boolean active;

    private String createdBy;
    
    private Point geom;


which complied perfectly as seems below:
Hibernate: 
   Hibernate: 
    create table objects_tbl (
        active boolean,
        creation_timestamp timestamp(6),
        alias varchar(255),
        created_by varchar(255),
        object_id varchar(255) not null,
        type varchar(255),
        geom geometry,
        object_details clob,
        primary key (object_id)
    )

the problem im dealing with, is that my crud which using this entity, cant i detect st_dwithin
public interface ObjectCrud extends JpaRepository<ObjectEntity, String> {
    
    @Query("SELECT o"
            + " FROM ObjectEntity o "
            + "WHERE st_dwithin(o.geom, st_point( :lng , :lat) ,:distance )  = true")
}

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.lang.Object' with right expression of type 'java.lang.Boolean'

my gradle and my proprties:
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=trace
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=trace
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping=trace


spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.5.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.locationtech.jts:jts-core:1.19.0'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-spatial:6.5.2.Final'
    
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql' // note postgresql support
    
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docker-compose' // note docker compose support
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher' // note test plan management support

im sitll entry level anything can help, thanks :frowning:
